# testng.xml file not execute all the method

Tags: testng.xml

I am trying to run a testng.suite but it is not running all methods from each class. It just ran first few methods from each class.I broke my .xml file into two .xml files. In one file I added first four classes and ran it successfully, testng.xml file ran every method from each class and did not miss even one method. Then I created a second .xml and ran my last class,
""
it was also successful and ran every method from this class. But when I run all five test classes in one .xml file it only run few methods form each class. Is there any limit of class/methods that we can run in one .xml file. How many classes/method we can run in one .xml file?
I did not understand this, I will really appreciate if some one help me here.
Below is my testng.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="finalSuite">
  <test name="final Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.qa.MurcryTour.Tests.HomePageTest"/>
      <class name="com.qa.MurcryTour.Tests.LoginPageTest"/>
      <class name="com.qa.MurcryTour.Tests.RegisterPageTest"/>
      <class name="com.qa.MurcryTour.Tests.FlightsPageTest"/>
      <class name="com.qa.MurcryTour.Tests.DataDriven_RegisterPageTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- final Test -->
</suite> <!-- finalSuite -->
```